# Join table on earlier joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Say I have got three tables: A, B and C.

```
A has primary key a
B has primary key a and also a non-primary key c.
C has primary key c.
```

I want to begin selecting from table A.

So I got a query like this:

```
Select * from A join B on A.a=B.a join C on B.c=C.c
```

It returns

Unknown column 'B.c' in 'on clause''

Is this impossible in mysql, joining a table on a joined table? Or am I just doing something wrong? BTW table and column names a made up.

Comment: Can you post the DDL for your tables. The error you're getting is simply stating that table B doesn't have a 'c' column.

Comment: Hero! As I have many tables alike table B, I was recommended to use aliases. I forgot to use those aliases in my on clauses too. Thanks for your alert response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, and your syntax should be correct.

please refer to this link for syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

example to interesting things you can do in MySQL (from the documentation):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4) ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c)
```

---

Also note the error claims that column C does not exist - so you should check the structure of B..